# Is there any way to easily determine the end/close of each open braces in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble debugging with my Javascript because each of my code blocks/functions has many conditions to meet

Let's say for example I have this code

```
    function sample(){ //1st open

    if(){ //2nd open
     if()
        { //3rd open

        } //3rd close
      blah blah blah....
    } //2nd close
blah blah blah...
    } //1st close
```

Is there any way that I can easily trace the end/closing braces of my codes? If I highlight the open brace the close braces will automatically highlight also.

Comment: Every IDE or javascript editor available should have this feature

Comment: Also, proper indentation will make this much more clear.

Comment: Adding so many comments will also make code looks confusing. Use standard IDE to highlight the syntax, and proper indent will make the code looks better.

Comment: Download sublime text or any if you cant afford to get standard IDEs, it provides the features too

Comment: Also not mixing up your braces style (*within a single function* no less) would probably help out.

Comment: A proper indentation will help you to make your code cleaner and readable

Comment: You guys mention IDE. Can you show me some link?. Sorry IDK about it.

Comment: Can you Google IDE?

Answer (score 1):

A proper text editor will have this feature

ie

Atom.io, Microsoft Visual Studio, Notepad++, Sublime

Comment: I know N++ has this function

Comment: ok so if you know this problem whats your issue then in debugging? XD

Comment: as for my example I have a 1 function that has many conditions sometimes I don't know where is my closing tag to it. That's why I ask if there is a way to have this kind of way that if I highlight the open tag the close tag will also be highlighted..